# how to dummy code using custom coding in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'testName':   [4402, 3747 ,5555,8754],
                   'moduleName':   ['singing', 'dance','booze', 'vocals'],
                   'endResult': ['WARNING', 'FAILED', 'WARNING', 'FAILED']})
```

I want to dummy code the test name and moduleName columns which I can achieve doing this:

```
dummy_cols= ['testName','moduleName']
df = pd.get_dummies(diag, columns=dummy_cols)
```

But however I want to dummy code it such that if it is WARNING in the endResult the dummy code should be 1 and if its FAILED it should be 2. So the output should have 1 and 2 corresponding to the endResult. How do I achieve this?

Desired Output:
`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'endResult': ['WARNING', 'FAILED', 'WARNING', 'FAILED'], 'testName_4402':[1,0,0,0], 'testName_3747':[0,2,0,0], 'testName_5555':[0,0,1,0], 'testName_8754':[0,0,0,2], 'moduleName_booze':[0,0,1,0], 'moduleName_dance':[0,2,0,0], 'moduleName_singing':[1,0,0,0], 'moduleName_vocals':[0,0,0,2]})`

Comment: what is your expected out put

Comment: Hi @Wen the output should look like this `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'endResult': ['WARNING', 'FAILED', 'WARNING', 'FAILED'],
                  'testName_4402':[1,0,0,0],
                  'testName_3747':[0,2,0,0],
                  'testName_5555':[0,0,1,0],
                  'testName_8754':[0,0,0,2],
                  'moduleName_booze':[0,0,1,0],
                  'moduleName_dance':[0,2,0,0],
                  'moduleName_singing':[1,0,0,0],
                  'moduleName_vocals':[0,0,0,2]})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.get_dummies, but then * 2 all raws with FAILED.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'testName':   [4402, 3747 ,5555,8754],
                   'moduleName':   ['singing', 'dance','booze', 'vocals'],
                   'endResult': ['WARNING', 'FAILED', 'WARNING', 'FAILED']})
df['testName'] = df['testName'].astype('category')
dummy_cols= ['testName','moduleName']

result = pd.get_dummies(df[dummy_cols]).join(df['endResult'])
result = result.apply(lambda x: x * 2 if x.endResult == 'FAILED' else x * 1, 1)
result['endResult'] = df['endResult']
```

Output:

```
testName_3747  testName_4402  testName_5555  testName_8754  \
0              0              1              0              0   
1              2              0              0              0   
2              0              0              1              0   
3              0              0              0              2   

   moduleName_booze  moduleName_dance  moduleName_singing  moduleName_vocals  \
0                 0                 0                   1                  0   
1                 0                 2                   0                  0   
2                 1                 0                   0                  0   
3                 0                 0                   0                  2   

  endResult  
0   WARNING  
1    FAILED  
2   WARNING  
3    FAILED
```